# Supervisor (Debian Strech) - couldn't chdir to Folder:EACCES

Tags: debian

First of all, thank you in advance for your help.

I am trying to use supervisor in order to launch gunicorn with a Flask (python3) project.
Unfortunately, the project is not starting:

```
root@play003:/home/debian# supervisorctl status 
play                       FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

Detail:

```
root@play003:/home/debian#cat /var/log/supervisor/play.log
supervisor: couldn't chdir to /var/www/Play : EACCES
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

Everything seems fine on the folder ownership 
:

```
root@play003:~$ ls -alh /var/www/
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       root       4.0K Sep 10 15:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root       root       4.0K Sep 10 14:47 ..
drwxrwx---  7 play       play       4.0K Sep 10 16:42 Play
```

My configuration :

```
root@play003:~$ cat /etc/supervisor/conf.d/froggyplay.conf 
[program:play]
user = play
directory = /var/www/Play
command = /var/www/Play/env/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 play:application

priority = 900
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stopsignal = TERM

redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
```

I have tested two versions of supervisor but I am currently in 3.3.5-1 (3.3.1-1 before that).

Do you have any idea why my project isn't starting ?

Thank you,
Romain

Answer (score 0):

I have found something interesting.

In order to progress, I have change the rights on the folders

```
root@play003:/var# chmod 755 www/
root@play003:/var/www# chmod 770 Play/
```

Answer (score 0):

Change permission of folder isn't good practice.

Try to add your user to the `www-data` group and set the folder owner like this:

```
sudo chown -R user:www-data /path/to/folder
```

Maybe you will need to add a group directive in the config file.

```
group=www-data
```